# python email multiple receiver, multiple attachment for error

Tags: python, email, attachment

```
    def mail():
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.utils import formatdate
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email import encoders
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt
    path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/pdf/'
    contact = 'con1.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(str(path)+contact, endcoding ='utf8')
    df.set_index('unyong', inplace = True)
    now = QDate.currentDate()
    filenm = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
    unyong_nm = []

    for w in filenm:
        a = w.find('_')
        b = w.rfind('_')
        unyong_nm.append(w[a+1:b])
    unyong_nm = list(set(unyong_nm))

    for i in range(0,len(unyong_nm)):

        send_from = 'ss@ddd'
        recipients = df.loc[unyong_nm[i],'email']
        send_to = ",".join(recipients)
        attach = [s for s in filenm if s.find(unyong_nm[i]) >-1 ]
        username = 'sss@ssss'
        password = 'sss'
        subject = ('111'+now.toString('yyyy.MM')+'_'+unyong_nm[i]+str(i+1))
        text = ('hi')


        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = send_from
        msg['To']= send_to
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['Date']=formatdate(localtime=True)


        filename_match = [s for s in filenm if s.find(unyong_nm[i]) >-1 ]

        for file in filename_match:
            part =MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(open(str(path)+file, 'rb').read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename =file)
            msg.attach(part)
            msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
            mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.sssss.com", 587)
            mailServer.ehlo()
            mailServer.starttls()
            mailServer.ehlo()
            mailServer.login(username,password)
            mailServer.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
            mailServer.close()
```

hi i have a problem with the email with attachment for statement.

the results of below def mail(),
multiple emails was sent to one person. (<- this is a error)
I want to send a each specific reciever with specific multiple attachments only once

why multiple email sented with diffrent number of attachements to one person.
the reciever have the 2 emails with a 1 attachment and, simultaneouly 2 attachment.
I want to send a email containg 2 attachments 
please help me.

*CF) path containg thoes files:
['2221_sss_love.pdf', '2221_sss_happy.pdf', '2221_ddd_sad.pdf', '2221_ddd_lucky.pdf', 'con1.xlsx']

*result
unyong_nm = ['sss','ddd']
filenm = ['2221_sss_love.pdf', '2221_sss_happy.pdf', '2221_ddd_sad.pdf', '2221_ddd_lucky.pdf']

---

*CF) con1.xlsx file contenxt:

unyong  email
sss     111@aaa
sss     777@bbb
ddd     666@sss
ddd     444@ccc

Answer (score 0):

The code is sending an email for each attachment.  By dedenting the mail-sending code, an email will be sent for each set of attachments grouped by 'ddd' or 'sss'.

```
    for file in filename_match:
        part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=file)
        msg.attach(part)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
    # Send mail outside the file grouping loop
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("localhost", 1025)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
```

The recipient selection code

```
recipients = df.loc[unyong_nm[i],'email']
send_to = ",".join(recipients)
```

might need to be changed, I can't tell because the contents of the dataframe aren't provided in the question.

Comment: why email is sent only first row 
sss 111@aaa    <- success
sss 777@bbb    <-fail
ddd 666@sss    <- success
ddd 444@ccc    <- fail


I want to send an email all of them.
the file name '2221_sss_love.pdf', '2221_sss_happy.pdf'  to  -> 111@aaa, 777@bbb
but only the email was sent to 111@aaa

'ddd' also has same problem